# How can I wait for copy to finish before batch file runs?

Tags: javascript, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create a batch file that will resize images placed in a folder and have a batch file "watch" the folder for changes.
I currently have this:

```
@echo off
set "source_folder=c:\src"
set "result_folder_1=c:\res1"

:start
if exist %source_folder%\*.jpg (
    for %%a in ("%source_folder%\*jpg") do (
        call scale.bat -source "%%~fa" -target "%result_folder_1%\%%~nxa" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
        del "%%~fa"
    )
)
goto start
```

And scale.bat is:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment 
        @echo off        
        cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %* 
        ::pause
        exit /b %errorlevel%       
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */ 

//https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630819(v=vs.85).aspx

var imageFile = new ActiveXObject("WIA.ImageFile"); 
var imageProcess = new ActiveXObject("WIA.ImageProcess");
var fileSystem = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var ARGS=WScript.Arguments;

/******
Scale filter description:

Scales image to the specified Maximum Width and Maximum Height preserving
Aspect Ratio if necessary.


MaximumWidth        - Set the MaximumWidth property to the width (in pixels)
                      that you wish to scale the image to.
MaximumHeight       - Set the MaximumHeight property to the height (in pixels)
                      that you wish to scale the image to.
PreserveAspectRatio - Set the PreserveAspectRatio property to True
                      [the default] if you wish to maintain the current aspect
                      ration of the image, otherwise False and the image will
                      be stretched to the MaximumWidth and MaximumHeight
FrameIndex          - Set the FrameIndex property to the index of a frame if
                      you wish to modify a frame other than the ActiveFrame,
                      otherwise 0 [the default]
                      

******/

//defaults

var maxWidth=0;
var maxHeight=0;

var pRatio=true;
var frameIndex=0;

var source="";
var target="";

var force=false;

var height=0;
var width=0;

var percentage=false;

////////////////////////////
////                      //
/**/     var QUALITY=100; //
////                      //
////////////////////////////

function existsFile(path){
    if (fileSystem.FileExists(path))
        return true;
}

function existsFolder(path){
    if (fileSystem.FolderExists(path))
        return true;
}

function deleteFile(path){
    fileSystem.DeleteFile(path);
}

function loadImage(image,imageFile){
    try{
       image.LoadFile(imageFile);
    }catch(err){
       WScript.Echo("Probably "+imageFile+" is not a valid image file");
       WScript.Echo(err.message);
       WScript.Quit(30);
    }
    height=image.Height;
    width=image.Width;
}

function ID2Format(id){
    var ids={};
    ids["{B96B3CAB-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"]="BPM";
    ids["{B96B3CAF-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"]="PNG";
    ids["{B96B3CB0-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"]="GIF";
    ids["{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"]="JPG";
    ids["{B96B3CB1-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"]="TIFF";
    
    return ids[id];
}

function format2ID(format){
    formats={};
    formats["BMP"]="{B96B3CAB-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";
    formats["PNG"]="{B96B3CAF-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";
    formats["GIF"]="{B96B3CB0-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";
    formats["JPG"]="{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";
    formats["TIFF"]="{B96B3CB1-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";
    
    return formats[format];
}

function convert(image,format){
    var ic=imageProcess.Filters.Count;
    var filterFormat=format2ID(format);
    if(filterFormat==null){
        WScript.Echo("not supported target format "+format);
        WScript.Quit(90);
    }
    imageProcess.Filters.Add(imageProcess.FilterInfos("Convert").FilterID);
    imageProcess.Filters(ic+1).Properties("FormatID").Value = filterFormat;
    imageProcess.Filters(ic+1).Properties("Quality").Value = QUALITY;
}

function scale(){
    if(maxHeight<=0){
        WScript.Echo("MaximumHeight ("+maxHeight+") should be bigger than 0");
        WScript.Quit(80);
    }
    
    if(maxWidth<=0){
        WScript.Echo("MaximumHeight ("+maxWidth+") should be bigger than 0");
        WScript.Quit(81);
    }
    
    var ic=imageProcess.Filters.Count;
    //var filterFormat=format2ID(format);
    imageProcess.Filters.Add(imageProcess.FilterInfos("Scale").FilterID);
    
    imageProcess.Filters(ic+1).Properties("MaximumWidth").Value = maxWidth;
    imageProcess.Filters(ic+1).Properties("MaximumHeight").Value = maxHeight;
    //WScript.Echo(pRatio+"::"+maxWidth+"::"+maxHeight+">>"+width+"++"+height);
    imageProcess.Filters(ic+1).Properties("PreserveAspectRatio").Value = pRatio;
    imageProcess.Filters(ic+1).Properties("FrameIndex").Value = frameIndex;
}

function fromPerc(){
    maxWidth=Math.round((width*maxWidth)/100);
    maxHeight=Math.round((height*maxHeight)/100);
    if(maxHeight==0)
        maxHeight=1;
    if(maxWidth==0)
        maxWidth=1;
}


function printHelp(){

    WScript.Echo( WScript.ScriptName + " - resizes an image");
    WScript.Echo(" ");
    WScript.Echo(WScript.ScriptName + "-source source.file -target file.format [-max-height height] [-max-width width] [-percentage yes|no] [-keep-ratio yes|no] [-frame-index -0.5..1] ");
    WScript.Echo("-source  - the image that will flipped or rotated.");
    WScript.Echo("-target  - the file where the transformations will be saved in.If the file extension format is different than the source it will be converted to the pointed one.Supported formats are BMp,JPG,GIF,TIFF,PNG");
    WScript.Echo("-percentage  - whether the rescale will be calculated in pixels or in percentages.If yes percentages will be used.Default is no.");
    WScript.Echo("-force  - If yes and the target file already exists , it will be overwritten");
    WScript.Echo("-max-height - max height of the image");
    WScript.Echo("-max-width - max width of the image");
    WScript.Echo("-keep-ratio - if dimensions ratio will be preserved.Default is yes");
    WScript.Echo("-frame-index - Have no idea what this is used for , but it is pressented in the rotation filter capabilities.Images with this and without looks the same.Accepted values are from -0.5 to 1");
    
}

function parseArguments(){
    if (WScript.Arguments.Length<4 || ARGS.Item(1).toLowerCase() == "-help" ||  ARGS.Item(1).toLowerCase() == "-h" ) {
        printHelp();
        WScript.Quit(0);
   }
   
    if (WScript.Arguments.Length % 2 == 1 ) {
        WScript.Echo("Illegal arguments ");
        printHelp();
        WScript.Quit(1);
    }
    
    //ARGS
    for(var arg = 0 ; arg<ARGS.Length-1;arg=arg+2) {
        if (ARGS.Item(arg) == "-source") {
            source = ARGS.Item(arg +1);
        }
        if (ARGS.Item(arg) == "-target") {
            target = ARGS.Item(arg +1);
        }

        if (ARGS.Item(arg).toLowerCase() == "-force" && (ARGS.Item(arg +1).toLowerCase() == "yes" || ARGS.Item(arg +1).toLowerCase() == "true") ) {
            force=true;
        }
        
        if (ARGS.Item(arg).toLowerCase() == "-percentage" && (ARGS.Item(arg +1).toLowerCase() == "yes" || ARGS.Item(arg +1).toLowerCase() == "true") ) {
            percentage=true;
        }
        
        if (ARGS.Item(arg).toLowerCase() == "-keep-ratio" && (ARGS.Item(arg +1).toLowerCase() == "no" || ARGS.Item(arg +1).toLowerCase() == "false") ) {
            pRatio=false;
        }
        
        if (ARGS.Item(arg).toLowerCase() == "-max-width") {
            try {
                maxWidth=parseInt(ARGS.Item(arg +1));               
            } catch (err){
                WScript.Echo("Wrong argument:");
                WScript.Echo(err.message);
                WScript.Quit(10);
            }
            
        }
        
        if (ARGS.Item(arg).toLowerCase() == "-max-height") {
            try {
                maxHeight=parseInt(ARGS.Item(arg +1));              
            } catch (err){
                WScript.Echo("Wrong argument:");
                WScript.Echo(err.message);
                WScript.Quit(15);
            }
            
        }
        
        
        if (ARGS.Item(arg).toLowerCase() == "-frame-index") {
            try {
                frameIndex=parseFloat(ARGS.Item(arg +1));
                if(frameIndex<-0.5 || frameIndex > 1){
                    WScript.Echo("Wrong argument - frame index should be between -0.5 and 1");
                    WScript.Quit(25);
                }
                
            } catch (err){
                WScript.Echo("Wrong argument:");
                WScript.Echo(err.message);
                WScript.Quit(20);
            }           
        }       
    }
    
    if (target==""){
        WScript.Echo("Target file not passed");
        WScript.Quit(5);
    }
    
    if(source==""){
        WScript.Echo("Source file not passed");
        WScript.Quit(6);
    }
}

parseArguments();

if(!existsFile(source)){
    WScript.Echo("Source image: " + source +" does not exists");
    WScript.Quit(40);
}

if(existsFile(target) && !force){
    WScript.Echo("Target image: " + target +" already exists");
    WScript.Quit(45);
}

if(existsFolder(target)){
    WScript.Echo("There's existing folder with the target file  (" + target +") name");
    WScript.Quit(46);
}

if(existsFile(target) && force){
    deleteFile(target);
}

var targetFormat=target.split(".")[target.split(".").length-1].toUpperCase();
loadImage(imageFile,source);
var sourceFormat=ID2Format(imageFile.FormatID);


if(maxWidth==0 && !percentage){
    maxWidth=width;
}

if(maxHeight==0 && !percentage){
    maxHeight=height;
}

if(maxWidth==0 && percentage){
    maxWidth=100;
}

if(maxHeight==0 && percentage){
    maxHeight=100;
}


if(percentage){
    fromPerc();
}



///
scale();
///

if (sourceFormat !== targetFormat ){
    convert(resImg,targetFormat);
}

var resImg=imageProcess.Apply(imageFile);
resImg.SaveFile(target);
```

It works, but if I copy multiple files in to source folder it could start the scale process while the copy is not done yet and it results in a message like "file is used by another process" and it skips this line and instead goes to deleting the file...
That is not what I want.

How can I make sure the call scale.bat happens only on files that has been copied and is ready to be scaled?

Comment: Perhaps you need some kind of *flush* function to force the JScript portion of your hybrid script to ensure completion of all file operation before going back to the batch file part…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your root issue is the continuous polling part looks for a .jpg but fires prematurely during the build of the .jpeg

The answer is simple to avoid that first copy files into the monitor folder as filename.tmp

then apply delays as appropriate ideally in input process on completion

```
copy output to folder\filename.tmp
ren filename.tmp filename.jpg
```

in your file monitor "watch" loop

```
timeout 1
call scale.bat
```

The alternative is to have a longer timeout in "watch" loop that allows for the worst case but that then slows that loop to a crawl.

One solution to that is use 2 loops so the incoming files are renamed with a filename_got.jpg on a much slower parallel loop whilst "watch" looks for *_got.jpg

**Later edit**

Probably the simplest is at start of "Watch" attempt `ren` in a loop.

If the file is not ready it should fail to be renamed on this pass, but be renamed once ready.

then only call scale with the renamed files.

```
@echo off
set "source_folder=c:\src"
set "result_folder_1=c:\res1"

:start
if exist %source_folder%\*.jpg (
    for %%a in ("%source_folder%\*jpg") do (
        ren "%%~na" "%%~na_got.jpg"
        call scale.bat -source "%%~na_got.jpg" -target "%result_folder_1%\%%~nxa" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
        del "%%~na_got.jpg"
    )
)
goto start
```

to avoid silly warnings that file does not exist then include

```
if exist "%%~na_got.jpg" call ...`
if exist "%%~na_got.jpg" del ...
```

Comment: I tried to add a timeout before the loop and it seems to work fine.